# Disable mouse selection using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to disable select using mouse down using the following code

```
var unFocus = function () {
  if (document.selection) {
    document.selection.empty()
  } else {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  }
}

document.getElementById("v_6").onmousemove = function () {
    unFocus()
}
document.getElementById("v_6").onmousedown = function () {
    unFocus()
}
```

My main issue is that I would like to have the code for onmousedown & onmousemove at the same time. so right now if I move the mouse without selecting the with onmousedown it removes the curser but I don't want that to happen. I would like to have it that if both events happen at the same time then it execute the function.
Any help with that would be much appreciated

Comment: If using JavaScript for this isn't actually a requirement, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) and you'll find the answer (which is good news) there. :-) *(I've also posted it as a community wiki below in hopes of staving off the eighteen posts that would have done so.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two answers:

1. If you really want to call `unFocus` when the mouse moves while the primary ("left") button is down, you can do that with just a `mousemove` handler, no `mousedown` handler is required, because the event object has a `buttons` value which has bitflags for which buttons are down; [more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove):

```
document.getElementById("v_6").onmousemove = function () {
    if (e.buttons & 1 === 1) { // true when the primary button is down
        unFocus()
    }
};
```

2. But if you just need to disallow user selection, and it doesn't have to be in JavaScript, just use [`user-select: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) in CSS for the elements:

```css
/* I've used #v_6 to match your example, but obviously it can be any selector */
#v_6 {
   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Example:

```css
.no-select {
   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div>You can select this text...</div>
<div class="no-select">...but not this text</div>
```

Comment: your code works for me great. but the only problem I would like help with is that I don't want to use v_6 as my selector. as this will restrict the code to that id only. I need to do something that would take any text area... would you be able to help with that?

Comment: @Fabian: Which approach are you going to take, #1 or #2? If #2, again, the selector can be any selector...

Comment: the css didn't work at all. but the JS is working. just need to do it .. I've added the following code but it won't work

Comment: $(window).load(function() {
    $(':input').addClass('coco');
});

document.getElementsByClassName("coco").onmousemove = function (e) {
    if (e.buttons & 1 === 1) {
        unFocus()
    }
}

Comment: @Fabian: All due respect, the CSS works perfectly on any vaguely modern browser. But if you're using jQuery: `$(document).on("mousemove", ".coco", function(e) { if (e.originalEvent.buttons & 1 == 0) { unFocus(); } });`

Comment: that's great,, again I'm sure your css may work with other setup! but not successful at my case :(

Comment: Also, do you know how can I stop double click select, please ?